# Separate jQuery UI tabs from content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hye Guys!!

I'am facing a small issue in jQuery UI Tabs. The problem is that I've tabs after my content as default behavior is, it should be before content.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="verticalTabs">  
  <div class="verticalTabsContent">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">djfhksdf kdsh kfh </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Content for Tab2 goes here</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">Content for Tab3 goes here</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">Content for Tab4 goes here</div>
  </div>
  <ul id="tabGroup">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Title_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Title_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Title_3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Title_4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
   $( "#verticalTabs" ).tabs();
});
```

It's working fine. But the problem is when I'm getting lists(ul - li) in my content. jQuery considering it as tabs instead my original tabs.

```
<div id="verticalTabs">  
  <div class="verticalTabsContent">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Content for Tab2 goes here</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">Content for Tab3 goes here</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">Content for Tab4 goes here</div>
  </div>
  <ul id="tabGroup">
    <li><a href="#tab1">title_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">title_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">title_3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">title_4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way, so that i can separate my tabs from content or can define tabs section manually

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).